# Understanding a complex SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm poor in SQL and when I got a SQL query below I was very confused about the `a` and `b` in it. What are their roles in the query and what's the function or result of this?

```
SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM abc_menu b WHERE b.parentId=a.id ) FROM abc_menu a ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

Comment: They are aliases. Perhaps read a basic tutorial...

Comment: You haven't seen complex SQL sentences

Comment: Where's the complex SQL query????

Comment: thx..where can I find how the aliases define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` and `b` are aliases -- in SQL, these are declared immediately after the table-name (in the FROM or JOIN clause) or after a column/ or select-expression.

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM abc_menu b WHERE b.parentId=a.id) 
FROM abc_menu a 
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

Here you can see the "outermost" access to the table is aliased (named within this statement) as `a`.

This distinguishes it from a subquery to count it's children, which references the same table separately aliased as `b`.

The rows which `b` refers to are logically independent from the rows that `a` refers to, and connected only as logically specified -- here, by the subquery WHERE clause `b.parentId=a.id`.